# How can I dynamically assign a value to a lightning record form?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, lightning-record-form

For example, my component has the following section that displays a record form:

```html
<template if:true={showRecordForm}>
    <lightning-record-form
        object-api-name={sObjectApiName}
        onsuccess={handleFormSuccess}
        record-type-id={recordTypeId}
        layout-type="Full"
        columns="2"
        oncancel={handleFormCancel}
        onload={handleFormLoad}>
    </lightning-record-form>
</template>
```

It will load the form for the object I specify in `sObjectApiName`, and with the specified record type as well. The problem is that I want to assign some values to specific fields.

Let us say that it is a Case form, and I want to assign an Account ID to the `AccountId` field, before the case is submitted to the platform.

I tried to query the `lightning-input-field`s, but with no success:

```js
const inputFields = this.template.querySelectorAll(
    'lightning-input-field'
);
if (inputFields) {
    inputFields.forEach(field => {
        console.log(field)
    });
}
```

This is a snippet from the [documentation of lightning-record-edit-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation).

I'm starting to think that this might not be viable, or too much trouble. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I think this can be done inside handlesubmit function. There is a example on the documentation.

Comment: But I don’t want to change the values on submit. I want fields to be set before the form is submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use edit form, why dont use - record-edit and try passing values

```js
@track recordInfo = {
    fields: [
        { name: "AccountId", value: "001000000000000AAA" },
        { name: "Description", value: "Description of this record." }
    ]
}

get recordInfoDefined () {
    return this.recordInfo !== undefined && this.recordInfo.fields !== undefined
}
```

```html
<lightning-record-edit-form
    object-api-name="Case">
    <template if:true={recordInfoDefined} for:each={recordInfo.fields} for:item="field">
        <lightning-input-field
            key={field.name}
            field-name={field.name}
            value={field.value}>
        </lightning-input-field>
    </template>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

Comment: I did end up using something like that yesterday. But instead of assigning the value directly to an attribute, I assigned it to an object that is the attribute. That way I can override/preload multiple fields without creating multiple attributes. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thank you. Can you add a snippet please. I wanted to understand how did you managed that - 'I assigned it to an object that is the attribute'

Comment: Do you mind if I add the snippet to your post, so it will be in the actual answer instead of the question? :)

Comment: It's fine. Thanks